# azure sql server database price

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I signed up for windows azure and I was given a 1gb database as part of my trial.  So my max size is 1gb and once I reach that size inserts will start to fail until I update the max size to 10gb.  Now my question is, if I update the max size now to 10gb and I only use 400mb, will I still be charged that the 1gb rate?  I think the answer is yes and if it is they why don't i just set the max size at 50gb so an insert never fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two editions: Web (1GB and 5GB) and Business (10GB through 50GB in 10GB increments). If you stay with a Web edition and go over the 1GB threshold on any given day, you'll be charged at the 5GB rate for that day. This is amortized daily over the month. So it's entirely possible you'll accrue costs just a little bit over the 1GB rate (if you upgrade to the 5GB Web Edition).

Moving to the Business edition, the lowest tier is 10GB, so that would be your baseline rate. Again, it's amortized daily.

If you want to set Web edition to 5GB (or Business edition to 50GB), you're going to avoid insert fails, as you pointed out. The tiers are going to help you when trying to manage cost.

See this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/16/10026036.aspx) detailing the tiers, along with information on the ALTER DATABASE command.

Comment: thanks, if i go to the business edition can i ever downgrade back to web?

Comment: @odyth Yes - upgrade/downgrade with the ALTER DATABASE command.

Comment: How is Windows Azure compared to other hosting service when talking about price? I am about to deploy a small website with little traffic, should I use WinAzure?

Comment: @Shimmy - no simple way to compare a hoster to Windows Azure. It's not all about price. Shared hosters cram hundreds of websites on a single box. It's simply comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the conclusion. I was asking about hosting websites in win-azure. So how do you compare azure to other hosters by both quality and cost, I really appreciate your response.

Comment: @Shimmy - that question simply doesn't fit the Q&A format here. It's subjective, and there's no simple answer. Sorry...